# Can I use a type within its own type definition?

Tags: f#, ocaml

I'm trying to define the following type:

```
type lToken =
  LInt of int 
| LString of string 
| LList of lToken list
| LFunction of string * LList
```

but I'm getting an error 'LList' is not defined.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do - i.e. use the types I'm defining inside their own type definition?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others pointed out, `LList` is not a name of a type, but just a name of discriminated union's constructor. In F#, cases of discriminated union happen to be compiled as .NET types, but that's just an implementation detail and you cannot refer to the generated types.

If you want to declare `LFunction` as a cast that consists of `string` and a `LList` then you can either expand the definition (as Brian and Marcelo suggest) or declare a new type (using `type .. and` to declare recursive types):

```
type List = Token list 
and Token = 
  | LInt of int  
  | LString of string  
  | LList of List
  | LFunction of string * List
```

PS: If you're writing F# then I'd recommend following standard naming guidelines and using `PascalCase` with a more descriptive name for type names. What does "l" stand for? Could you expand it (thanks to type inference, you won't need to write the type name anyway).

Comment: I would normally go for more descriptive names, but I'm just playing around in the language by writing a simple interpreter for a lispesque language. Basically, trying to learn the language a bit better by writing something that is pretty self contained, but not entirely trivial either!

Comment: @MrBear: Yes, I mainly wrote the "PS" because I named one type `List` which would colide with F# `List` type. Using `LispList` would be nicer :-)

Answer (score 6):

`LList` is a constructor, not a type. Just use the associated type directly:

```
...
| LFunction of string * (lToken list)
```

(My ML is very rusty; I'm not sure whether the parentheses are right.)

Comment: I don't think you need the parentheses - 

| LFunction of string lToken list

seems to work just fine. I'm still in the process of learning the language and I think I'm confusing myself a little along the way as I try to map ideas I know from other languages onto ML.

Sadly it takes a while to wrap your head around everything!

Answer (score 4):

`LList` is not the name of a type; `lToken` is.  Perhaps you want `lToken list` there instead?